# Proof that any hyperbolic group has Rapid Decay property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory

A classic result that states that any hyperbolic group in the sense of Gromov has Rapid Decay property in the sense of Jolisaint. But the original proof of that fact is contained in an old Ph.D. dissertation, written in French. Can someone help me to find the proof in English?

Comment: It's been proved by Drutu and Sapir that hyperbolic groups relative to RD subgroups have RD. Hence hyperbolic groups follow as a particular case. *(Relatively hyperbolic groups with rapid decay property. Int. Math. Res. Not. 2005, no. 19, 1181–1194.)* https://doi.org/10.1155/IMRN.2005.1181 https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405500

Comment: My favority proof is in Sapir's article *The rapid decay property and centroids in groups* (arxiv.org/abs/1405.0757).